# Passing params in router vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

I’m having a problem. I can’t get it to work.

I have this component called Projet. Inside of it, I have this block of code:

i want when i click in project it will take me to another detailpage
but nothing happen:

```
{path: '/detail/:id', component: detail}
```

and this the code in my components

```
        <tr v-for="projet in projets" :key="projet.id" >
           <router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: {id:  projet.id } }" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;">        <td>{{ projet.name }}</td></router-link>
                  <td>{{ projet.owner }}</td>
                  <td>{{ projet.durre }}</td>

                  <td>-------</td>
                  <td><i  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#description" class="fas fa-scroll" ></i></td>
                  <td>{{projet.budget}}</td>
                  <td>      <a href="#" @click="deleteProjet(projet.id)" ><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the router name.

try this

```
{path: '/detail/:id', component: detail, name: 'detail'}
```

Comment: then make a log of your project @anis

Comment: project.id work he take me to other page but there is no id in the url of the new page

Comment: if projet.id not found then it will show undefined. and you will redirect to /detail/undefined page

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%20name:%20'detail',%20params:%20%7Bid:%20%20projet.id%20%7D%20%7D 
take me to this url

Comment: your templates not compiling, check vue instance, vue files. and see in your console log

Comment: its run by remplacing by  :to="`/detail/${projet.id}`"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<router-link :to="'detail/' + projet.id" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;">
```